# Buliding a user profile with NSDictionary or NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to create an application that stores profile information..

**Name: first Last**
**Email:**
**Department:**
**Title:**

What would be the best approach?...

I was thinking of using an `NSDictionary` for the info.
But I'm unclear on how to combine all the attributes of the profile, into the `NSDictionary`...
Would I create an `NSDictionary` for NAMES, then another for EMAILS, ect...?

Any insight is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use NSDictionary at all? Why not make a class to represent a 'User' and store the information as attributes of the class? Usually, people use NSDictionary to map arbitrary keys to values, where the keys need not be part of a small set like 'NAME', 'EMAIL' (which is what will happen in your case), and need not be known at compile time.

Comment: xcode is just an IDE. tagging this question xcode, xcode4 and xcode4.2 makes no sense.

Comment: what do you call "profile information" ? Did you mean "user defaults" or the possibility to manage multiple profiles within the application ?

Comment: @Vince..Yes I meant exactly that to manage multiple profiles..

Comment: @Vince..Yes I meant exactly that to manage multiple profiles.. How wold you suggest I go by doing this... Should I create a Class which manages user profiles.. and create a methods for each of my attributes, such as Name, Email, ect.. ?

Comment: @dec - the question becomes harder then.. Not implemented that yet, but `NSDictionary` is fine for storing object with keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is directed at those who suggest a struct: I'm sorry but why even bother using Objective-C if you're not going to use Objective-C? I'm not sure where this "use a struct" trend is coming from but it's absurd when considering primary, first-class app objects that are to be heavily manipulated with the Cocoa API.

To the OP: Use an Objective-C class and be done with it.

An NSDictionary is great as an indistinct container or map and, provided everything in it is  compliant, the whole thing (container and contents) can be archived and unarchived with one line of code.

In your case, you already know a predefined set of attributes (and maybe even methods) of this object you want to describe (a Profile), so create an Objective-C class and make it NSCoding compliant so you can stash it in any standard Cocoa container and have it easily archived/unarchived, etc. You can also take advantage of automagic behavior such as having a -fullName property that returns a concatenation of the first and last names while participating rather effortlessly in Key Value Observing, using NSPredicate filters, sorting by key etc. You can also implement -copyWithZone: so a Profile instance is easily copyable, etc.

"Why use a *hammer* on that nail? It's wasteful. Plenty of perfectly good sticks out there you can put rocks on."

Please ... just use a class. It makes functionality so much simpler to add in the long run.

Comment: You could also mention that you can't use Objective-C objects in structs under ARC.

Comment: @Joshua...So would you proceed like I've mentioned above? create a Class which has NSCoding compliant properties and proceed from there...or what do you recommend?

Comment: @dec: Yes. Absolutely. It sounds like a primary model object in your application - a logical thing your app manages for the user - so it should be a proper class. Were it a struct, you'd be very limited in what you could do with it. VERY. All the typical things you'll usually do with it in Cocoa would be an uphill battle. Structs are perfectly valid for flat out data manipulation but should chosen for specific, valid reasons, defaulted to for Cocoa/Objective-C applications.

Comment: @Abizem: You actually *can* use structs with ARC but they're even fussier: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.restrictions.records

Comment: Joshua Nozzi and @quixoto: Thank you for the correction. I have deleted my answer since using structs is as bad as you say. But I did figure it would do for simple cases.

Comment: @Joshua  It is primary.. The App will have to retrieve users info giving the user the ability to edit info or even view other profiles as well.. question would you suggest putting the contain in the same Implementation file, or should I create a separate class for that?

Comment: @dec Don't confuse the container into which you store instances of Profile with the instances of Profile. At this point, you should read the Model View Controller text: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: @dec The idea is, you have some central controller (which will hold a pointer to a container - an NSMutableArray, for example) that knows how to create a new Profile instance, edit it, and stash it in the container to keep it around. That's a pretty broad subject, so read the docs and post separate, specific questions as they arise.

Answer (score -2):

I know there is a NSUserDefaults object. I haven't worked with it.
There is a [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/) that explains NSUserDefaults